# how to send a link in MMS message?

Tags: android

i want to send a link for www.google.com in mms, but i want that its shows only "Google". when user click on "Google" its link www.google.com should be open. please suggest its solution, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this directly in a SMIL file, which may look like this:

```
<smil>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
    </body>
</smil>
```

This should be the only attachment to the MMS.